# Minikube(K8s)- Docker is nearly out of disk space, which may cause deployments to fail! (87% of capacity). You can pass '--force' to skip this check

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to restart my minikube using below command

```
`minikube start --driver=docker`
```

But getting  below error
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cizm3.png)

I have tried to delete the running minikube container and then the minikube image
and also tried command

```
docker system prune
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run "docker system prune" to remove unused Docker data (better with "-v" or even "-a")
2. Increase the storage allocated to Docker for Desktop by clicking on:
   Docker icon > Preferences > Resources > Disk Image Size
3. Run "minikube ssh -- docker system prune" if using the Docker container runtime

If it doesn't help, reset the Docker Desktop setting to default. Bug icon > Reset to factory defaults.